# Assembly INVOKE A procedure

Tags: assembly, masm

I am trying to invoke a simple procedure in assembly, but I cannot get it to work properly.

I do have the prototype defined in the data segment as

```
    mySearch PROTO,
map: PTR BYTE,
char: BYTE
```

Then I have the procedure right before the END main (in main.asm)

```
   mySearch PROC, string: PTR BYTE, char: BYTE
     ret
    mySearch ENDP
```

I am invoking the procedure as:

```
mov ebx, LENGTHOF msg1
INVOKE mySearch , ADDR myString, ebx
```

IF I lose the second parameter

> char: BYTE

My program compiles. So, my problem is, i dont understand how to pass a character to  my procedure.

Comment: it's been a while since I did assembly, but I seem to recall that you would push it onto the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be any ',' after PROTO or PROC.
So it should look like:

```
mySearch PROTO map: PTR BYTE, char: BYTE



mySearch PROC string: PTR BYTE, char: BYTE
 ret
mySearch ENDP
```

Answer (score 0):

For calling procedure you better should move `arguments` in

> registers

OR you may

> push

them on `stack`.